# How to check whether parameter is in the choices?

Tags: python, django, model

There is an inner class Option in the model A.The snippet is as below:

```
class A(models.Model):
    class Option(object):
        UNKNOWN = 0
        CASH = 1
        STORE_CREDITS = 2

        @classmethod
        def get_choices(cls):
            return ((cls.UNKNOWN, "UNKNOWN"),
                    (cls.CASH, "CASH"),
                    (cls.STORE_CREDITS, "STORE_CREDITS"))
```

let's say there is an integer variable `a`, Is there any elegant way to check whether `a` is a valid option by using the `get_choices` method?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you could get the `get_choices` method to return a single list,

`if a in get_choices(<param>)`

is always an option. Or as you have it now, you may be able to get away with...

```
for item in get_choices(<param>):
    if a == item[0]:
        ...
```

Therefore checking if `a` is equal to the number value stored in the variables being returned in each list.